# How to use get() to construct a complicated model of variables

Tags: r, function, evaluation

I know how to use `get()` to construct an model on the fly from a variable, for example:

```
dvar="myResponse"
ivar="someIndependentVariable"
family="binomial"
myGLM <- glm(data=ds, get(dvar) ~ get(ivar),family=myFamily)
```

This is handy for looping through a list of variables, of course -- you could feed it a list of independent variables in a `for()` loop, and look at a number of different models.  My question is, how would I use `get()`, `eval()`, or some similar commands to create more complex calls?  For example, suppose I have **two** independent variables in a list:

```
dvar="myResponse"
ivar=c("independentVar1","independentVar2")
```

and what I want, in the end, is this:

```
myGLM<-glm(data=ds, myResponse ~ independentVar1 + independentVar2)
```

I know I could do this with three `get()` statements, given that I only have 1 dependent and 2 independent variables, but is there a general way to do it for an n-item list of independent variables?   Basically, what I'm up to is something like stepwise regression, but I'm not happy with any of the existing options in `caret`, `MASS`, and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

You want `?reformulate` ...

```
dvar="myResponse"
ivar <- c("independentVar1","independentVar2")
form <- reformulate(ivar, response=dvar)
glm(form, myFamily = family_string, data= ...)
```

As a general rule,

- solutions that use `reformulate()` or those that manipulate the formula directly (with `quote()`, `substitute()`, `as.symbol()` etc.) are more idiomatic/safer/more robust than ...
- string-based solutions (`deparse()`/`as.formula()`) which are idiomatic/safer/more robust than ...
- solutions with `[m]get()`, `eval()`, etc ...

(I'm actually cheating on this hierarchy a little bit here since `reformulate()` is actually string-based, but since it's a built-in function ...)